# YouTube JavaScript player starts to play the video when seekTo is called

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Accordring to the [YouTube IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#seekTo) the `seekTo` method should start to play the video unless the player state is "paused". That would be OK if there was any way to put the player in this state. Here is a fiddle that calls `pauseVideo` to put the player in the "paused" state. Then it calls `seekTo`. The video starts playing.

Do I read the docs wrong in any way? Or is this a bug in the YouTube player?

http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/r46ofyz0/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With youtube it seems `paused` means that you have requested the video to pause, unlike HTML5 video where paused simply means "not playing"

You can check the state with [`instance.getPlayerState()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status). Anything except `2` (paused) should trigger playing. In this case it seems to be `video cued` (5).

I [created an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/77752719) for what I think is the real problem (pauseVideo doesn't do anything), using a fork of your jsfiddle. It may not be considered to be a bug though. We'll see.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is the way I see it too. (I did not know about the Google issue tracker. And I see it does perhaps not work correctly, no response on https://issuetracker.google.com/77752719. Beside that it say "0 people has starred this issue" - but I can't see any way to star it??)

Comment: You press the star in order to "star" it. For me it's in the top left in the middle column, but it might differ across devices and screen sizes. I haven't got any experience with the issue tracker either so I don't know quite what to expect.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can see the star there. (But it is very pale.)

Comment: It looks like they have not read the bug report at all - one year later. Is there another way to reach them?

Comment: I wouldn't expect them to prioritize this @Leo

Comment: Though if they do not fix it that means that the HTML5 video API is superior in this regards. The YouTube API seekTo is simply unusable (or you have to explain the bug to users...)

Comment: The status of the bug is still "new". Two years after you created the issue.